# polyglossia breaks pgf math (cont.)

Tags: polyglossia, pgfmath, german

I found that polyglossia with setlanguage to german breaks pgfmath. I read several hints on this and ended up with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=false]{german} % problem is here
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,babel}
\begin{document}
\def\swNames{{"ERP", "CRM", "Analytics", "DB", "SCM"}}%
\foreach [count=\i] \farbe in {yellow, orange, green, blue} {%
  Name \i: \pgfmathparse{\swNames[\i-1]}\pgfmathresult, }
\end{document}
```

The result should be:
`Name 0: ERP, Name 1: CRM, Name 2: Analytics, Name 3: DB,` line 3 (the line marked % problem is here) commented out

But I got:
`Name 0: 0, Name 1: 0, Name 2: 0, Name 3: 0,`

and the error:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `ERP' (in '{"ERP", "CRM", "Analytics
", "DB", "SCM"}[1-1]').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10 ...gfmathparse{\swNames[\i-1]}\pgfmathresult, }
                                                  
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.
```

System used TeXlive2020 on ubuntu 22.04.lts AND Overleaf as of 2023-01-16

Any hint for help is very welcome.
Regards
Lutz-Peter

Answer (score 1):

your example runs without error in texlive 2022 lualatex and this output

[image]

In older releases you seem to need to for `"` to be safe, for example

```
\edef\swNames{{\detokenize{"ERP", "CRM", "Analytics", "DB", "SCM"}}}%
```

works in texlive 2021 (and overleaf's texlive 2022, which misses some updates)

Answer (score 1):

The `babelshorthands=false` option doesn't change the fact that `"` is made active. This used to be a problem until TeX Live 2022, where your problem doesn't show up.

If you're tied to TeX Live 2021 or earlier, you can define your arrays to contain a standard double quote character.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,babel}

\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=false]{german} % problem is here

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\definepgfarray}[1]{%
  \begingroup\catcode`"=12
  \definepgfarray@{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\definepgfarray@}[2]{%
  \endgroup\def#1{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\definepgfarray\swNames{{"ERP", "CRM", "Analytics", "DB", "SCM"}}

\foreach [count=\i] \farbe in {yellow!95!magenta, orange, green!90!blue, blue!90!red} {%
  Name \i: \pgfmathparse{\swNames[\i-1]}\textcolor{\farbe}{\pgfmathresult}, }

\end{document}
```

[image]